# pass input parameters to stored procedure from sql table

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

i want to pass input parameters like start date and end date in the table T1 and pass to stored procedure SP1 from T1.is it possible,and also i want to execute this sp in c# script task in ssis.Thanks

Comment: If I may ask, why does this need to be executed from a stored procedure in a C# task? Is that a business requirement or an assumption on your part of how to perform the task?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Which sp is the one you want to execute in the c# script task?  Why do you want to do it in a script task?

Comment: Thanks,yes it is businness requirement that in the sp there are 2 input parameters which input values are stored in the table like 100 values and i have to pass it dynamically one by one as input parameter in stored procedure..

Comment: Ann,i have one sp which having 2 input parameter like startdate and enddate and i want to get these input parameter values from the table whcih are stored for e.g 100 rows,and i want to execute the SP corresponding the input paramter value like if SP executes first time then it will take input parmeter as '17-6-2013','18-6-2013' and so on..i hope this would you give clear idea on my prob.thanks

Comment: But you can use a stored procedure, with parameters, in an `Execute SQL Task` as well as in OLE Source/ADO .NET source components. Is it really required to call the stored procedure from C# that I'm questioning

Comment: yes i can same but how will pass input paramteres from the table in case of executing it through execute sql task control?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this out for both : with '?'s and with C#
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/passing-variables-to-and-from-an-ssis-task/

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have sort out the problem initially i took the execute sql task and select the values from the table and store those value in the result set an after that i have taken dataflow task and oled source connection and execute the sp in that and pass the earlier result set values to the stored procedure and execute it and store the rsult in the one sql table.